# Kannel: get sms status from database

Tags: symfony, kannel

I'm making a symfony application that stores a huge amount of SMS in the database and Kannel detectes these Sms and sends , I'm using the sqlbox for sure, the problem that Kannel notifies our symfony app about an sms throug the dlr-url which is causing alot of memory usage of apache, cause for every Sms we got about 3 http request from the dlr to update the sms so for 100k sms we get 300k request and in each request we update the database...

So what I'm thinking of is that why not Kannel update the sms status in the database directly without calling the dlr url... is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, your tests are based on the following configuration:

- `sqlbox` to send messages (through insert in `send_sms` table
- `dlr_url` set in your configuration to get delivery reports
- no custom `dlr-storage`

### How to keep DLR without using additional http calls

There is already a tool to get automatically DLR into a database: that is the interest of `dlr-storage`

In Kannel documentation, you will see that this field has several possibilities:

> Supported types are: internal, spool, mysql, pgsql, sdb, mssql,
>   sqlite3, oracle and redis. By default this is set to internal.

From my experience, when using a **database dlr-storage, the delivery reports (DLR) are only kept in datatable while the delivered status has not been received, then they are automatically deleted**.

So if you wish to keep some logs about the sent items, you need to edit some files (`gw/dlr_mysql.c` and `gw/dlr.c`) to avoid this delete.

### Configuration of the dlr-strorage

Here I will provide an example with MySql.

Sample of additional configuration in `kannel.conf` file:

```
# this line must be in the "core" group
dlr-storage = mysql

#---------------------------------------------
# DLR STORAGE
#
# 
group = mysql-connection
id = mydlr
host = localhost
username = *yourMySqlUserName*
password = *yourMySqlPass*
database = *yourMySqlDatabaseWithTheDlrTable*
max-connections = 1

# Group defining where are the data in the db (table, columns)
group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = dlr
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = ts
field-destination = destination
field-source = source
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxc
```

Comment: Your response is too late, I finished this project and we just improved the hardware and optimized apache to handle the dlrs, but anyway, I liked your idea, this may help me in a new project, Thank you :)

Comment: I hoped that you finished your project since January :) but yes the idea was to help people, thanks for your feedback on my answer